# Solve $\cos 2x - \sin 2x = \sqrt 3\cos 4x$

Tags: trigonometry

How do I solve this trig equation?

$$\cos 2x - \sin2x = \sqrt{3} \cos 4x$$

I have tried in different ways. But I can't get to a final answer.Please help.

My work is,

$$\cos 2x - \sin 2x = √3(\cos 2x - \sin 2x)(\cos 2x + \sin 2x)$$
$$⇔(\cos 2x - \sin 2x)((1-√3(\cos 2x + \sin 2x))= 0$$
 Then,
$$\tan 2x = 1  \ \ \  \text{or}  \ \ \   (\cos 2x + \sin 2x)= \dfrac1{\sqrt3}$$

I don't know whether this way is correct. Please someone help for a better solution.

Comment: Show us the work from your different attempts.  That will help us better understand any misunderstandings you might have, and what you may have overlooked.

Comment: I have tried writing the cos 4x as (cos 2x)^2-(sin 2x)^2

Comment: It should be $\cos^2 2x - \sin^2 2x$

Comment: actually, what you wrote is common short-hand and means precisely what the asker used.  Nimantha: note that $(\cos 2x)^2 = \cos^2(2x)$.  So you are indeed correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to solve that
$$\cos2x-\sin2x=\sqrt3(\cos2x-\sin2x)(\cos2x+\sin2x),$$
which gives $\cos2x-\sin2x=0$, which is $x=\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\pi}{2}k,$ $k\in\mathbb Z$ or
$$\cos2x+\sin2x=\frac{1}{\sqrt3},$$ which is
$$\cos\left(2x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt6},$$
which gives $x=\frac{\pi}{8}\pm\frac{1}{2}\arccos\frac{1}{\sqrt6}+\pi k$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use $\cos2y=\cos^2y-\sin^2y$ in $\cos4x=\cos2(2x)$

Also,  for $\sqrt3(\cos2x+\sin2x)=1,$  $$\cos\left(2x-\dfrac\pi4\right)=\dfrac1{\sqrt6}$$

$$\implies2x-\dfrac\pi4=2m\pi\pm\arccos\dfrac1{\sqrt6}$$ where $m$ is any integer.